# How to check if a class mixin has been applied to a Polymer element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I would like to check if a mixin has been applied to a custom element, but I don't think I can use 'instanceof', since a mixin is not properly a base class (I tried, of course).
I would need to enforce that an element added to a collection can be only of a kind with a particular class mixin applied...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you question correctly.

I assume you want to check something like `MyCustomElement` has already apply `MyMixin` or not?

You can check from the instance

```
let instance = new MyCustomElement()
console.log(instance instanceof MyMixin)
```

This will only work when `MyMixin` is a class not a factory function. If you follow documentation you need to change it.

Another way, you can declare some static function in `MyMixin`. Then you can call from `MyCustomElement` to check it.